# Glob pattern with amazon s3

Tags: regex, amazon-s3

I want to move files from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket.I want to move only files whose name starts with "part".I can do it by using java.But is it possible to do it with amazon CLI. Can we use GlobPattern in CLI.
my object name are like:
    part0000
    part0001

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this is possible through the aws CLI, using the `--include` and `--exclude` options.

As an example, you can use the `aws s3 sync` command to sync your part files:

```
aws s3 sync --exclude '*' --include 'part*' s3://my-amazing-bucket/ s3://my-other-bucket/
```

You can also use the `cp` command, with the `--recursive` flag:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive --exclude '*' --include 'part*' s3://my-amazing-bucket/ s3://my-other-bucket/
```

Explanation:

- `aws`: The aws CLI command
- `s3`: The aws service to interface with
- `sync`: The command to the service to do
- `--exclude <value>`: The UNIX-style wildcard to ignore, except by include statements
- `--include <value>`: The UNIX-style wildcard to act upon.

As noted in [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters), you can also specify `--include` and `--exclude` multiple times.

Comment: Thank You,This one helped me

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `aws s3 mv --exclude '*' --include 'zQm*` s3://... s3://...`. For me nothing happens, the command just ends with nothing.

Comment: Oh I needed `--recursive` when using `mv`.

Comment: Why is --exclude needed?