# file pattern matching with aws-cli s3 sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, glob

I'm wondering what the easiest way is to search for specific files when using the aws s3 sync.  I want to specifically look for image files under directories that are 4 numeric digits long.

essentially I need a case insensitive search for a pattern similar to:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)
```

aka or including all of the following:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*.[Pp][Nn][Gg]
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*.[Gg][Ii][Ff]
```

Comment: for any moderator types, another possible option for the new tag might also be aws-cli-s3-sync

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glob pattern with amazon s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363027/glob-pattern-with-amazon-s3)

Comment: See: [AWS CLI: Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: I've actually looked at both those threads. But while they show more ambiguous globbing techniques, I can't seem to find anything that speaks of matching a specific number of characters with specific types of character ranges such as digits or specific letters. And the above I tried does not seem to work.

Comment: By the way, I included those examples because those examples 'do' work in the shell and with some other 'exclude/include' file formats. Just not with 'aws s3 sync' - not as shown